# Resize after droppable is not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am going through the odd problem ,, The things are messed up between the Resizable and the droppable Jquery Events .

**Problem**

I have div which i can easily resize . but i am not able to resize after i drag and drop this div into the droppable area. Can any one help about this.

This is my [**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/c38WX/25/)

I have following code

Jquery

```
 function makeDraggable() {
            $(".selectorField")
                .draggable({
                    containment: $('body'),
                    helper: "clone",
                   cursor: "move",
                    cancel: null
                });
        }
        $(function () {
            var _ctrl_index = 1001;
            $(".resize_box").resizable({ handles: 'e' });

            makeDraggable();
            $(".droppedFields").droppable({
                accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    var draggable = ui.draggable;
                    draggable = draggable.clone();
                    draggable.appendTo(this);
                    makeDraggable();
                }
            });

        });
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="selectorField resize_box" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: green;"></div>

<div style="height:100px; width:100px;" ></div>
    <div id="Section1" style="height: 100px; line-height: 20px; width: 100%; border: 1px dotted red; display: table;">

        <div class="well droppedFields ui-sortable" style="width: 73px;"></div>

    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 #Section1 > div {
            display: table-cell;
            border-right: 1px dotted red;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apologies, I mis-read the question. The element is not resizable after dragging because the cloned element does not have re-sizable attached to it.

After cloning draggable, also re-attach the handle, using the existing handle element.

```
var draggable = ui.draggable;
draggable = draggable.clone();
draggable.resizable({ handles: {'e': '.ui-resizable-e'} });
draggable.appendTo(this);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c38WX/31/)

Comment: *"but i am not able to **resize** after i drag and drop this div into the droppable area."*

Comment: i m also unable to resize after i drag and drop this div into the droppable area

Comment: @TJ can you help a little

Comment: Apologies, I misread the question. Updated my answer to allow for resizing after drag and drop.

Comment: Doesnt working at me side,, will see aftr the day tomorow, today have a lack off time thanks man, i hope it can help , @cjspurg

Comment: @cjspurg +1. use `@` followed by username so that users will be notified about the comment... I updated the fiddle to reduce amount of code http://jsfiddle.net/c38WX/32/

Comment: hi @cjspurg ... Are you around, things on my side are messed up can you come here for a little help

Comment: Yes it is not working, if u aloow we can discuss, may be this can solve the prblm @TJ

Comment: @ColdCoffee It's working for me in the fiddle. Can you just update the fiddle with your code an explain what's the issue..?